# Encrypt a database connection using pymssql

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pymssql

How can I make the connection to the msssql database using pymsssql?
Below is a snippet of my code where I try to make the connection encrypted

```
conn = pymssql.connect(
            server=conn.host,
            user=conn.login,
            password=conn.password,
            database=self.schema or conn.schema,
            port=conn.port,
        )
        return conn
```

Comment: In case you weren't aware, [The Pymssql Project is Being Discontinued](https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/668). It's therefore recommended you switch to a different library.

Comment: Does that mean, we can't encrypt with this? @Larnu

Comment: No, I'm saying that ideally you should be looking to switch off pymssql in the future.

Comment: I understood @Larnu . But what suggestion would you give as a temporary fix in this case?

Comment: Where exactly are you telling it that the connection needs to be encrypted? Have you tried creating an alias in your [freetds.conf file](https://www.freetds.org/userguide/freetdsconf.html) yet with `encryption=require` and `check certificate hostname=no`?

Comment: What happens if you force it from the server side using the server setting `Force protocol encryption: Yes`

Comment: I am using pymssql verion 2.1.5, I don't have freetds file in my system. How can I check if it am uses encryption with this? or tell me how to do this freetds installations?@AlwaysLearning

Comment: pymssql builds on top of FreeTDS to manage connections to SQL Servers. If you don't have a freetds.conf file anywhere on your system yet there are two places you can create it as described in my previous link.

Comment: @Larnu It might be a bit confusing, but that deprecation notice by the pymssql maintainers has been reverted a quite a while ago ... https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/releases/tag/v2.1.5